# "Not in function" error in recursive function

Tags: python, function, recursion, tree

I'm writing an algorithm to count the total amount of nodes a tree has. This is the code:

```
def tree_nodes(tree):
    """Given a tree, returns the total amount of nodes it has."""
    def recursive_node_count(node):
        """Recursive count function."""
        childs = tree[node]
        if childs == None:
            return 1
        else:
            nodes_so_far = 0
            for i in xrange(len(childs)):
                nodes_in_this_branch = recursive_node_count(childs[i])
                nodes_so_far += nodes_in_this_branch          
            return nodes_so_far

    root = tree['root']
    total_nodes = recursive_node_count(root)
    return total_nodes
```

The `tree` is basically a dictionary of lists. Example:

```
tree = {0: [1], 1: [2], 2: [3, 4], 3: None, 4: None, 'root': 0}
```

[image]

When I try to run my code, this is the output I receive:

```
at Answer.py. not in a function on line 31
at Answer.py. in recursive_node_count on line 31
at Answer.py. in recursive_node_count on line 31
at Answer.py. in recursive_node_count on line 31
at Answer.py. in recursive_node_count on line 31
at Answer.py. in recursive_node_count on line 31
at Answer.py. in recursive_node_count on line 31
at Answer.py. in recursive_node_count on line 31
at Answer.py. in recursive_node_count on line 31
at Answer.py. in recursive_node_count on line 31
at Answer.py. in tree_nodes on line 36
at Answer.py. in <module> on line 96
```

These are the lines `31` (inside the function definition), `36` (inside the definition too) and `96` (a call to the definition) in the original code:

```
31: nodes_in_this_branch = recursive_node_count(childs[i])
36: total_nodes = recursive_node_count(root)
96: nodes = tree_nodes(tree)
```

I checked the syntax, indentation, tabs, white spaces, but I can't find the error. I'm a beginner in Python. Could you guys please help me?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the error that you were having, was there something that was printed before what you posted in the output?

Comment: Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/mDyPPytn

Comment: By the way, the answer to your question is that nothing was printed before. The whole code there a single print in the last line of it.

Comment: I mean to ask, was there anything else printed in the error message?

Comment: No, this is the whole output when I run the code.

Comment: Hmm, when I run all of the code from the pastebin, I get an exception that `struct_row` (on line 80) is undefined, and indeed it is not assigned to before that point. Can you give me the sample input that is causing the error above?

Comment: Input: http://pastebin.com/TiCziSyZ

Comment: I am not getting the error you are getting exactly, but I do get a maximum recursion depth exceeded error. This can be caused by actually having a tree that is deeper than python's default recursion depth, more likely in this case, having a loop in your tree. For example `tree = {0: [1], 1: [0], 'root': 0}` would cause infinite recursion. I suspect that is the real reason for your error. (I increased the maximum recursion depth to make sure that wasn't the cause.) The changes required in this case are outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75649/discussion-between-renatov-and-tyler-cloutier).

Comment: @TylerCloutier the recursion would be infinite because your example is not a tree, by definition. For this sort of graph, I would need and entire different algorithm. But the function I posted is intended to receive only trees.

Comment: Yes, clearly, that data structure is not a tree. I am suggesting that the dictionary that you are passing to that function is malformed and contains a loop. It is likely a bug elsewhere in the program that creates the malformed tree (ie a graph with a loop)

Comment: @TylerCloutier ok, I'll check that, thanks!

Comment: @renatov If your query was resolved, do accept an answer that helped you the most to mark this as resolved.

Comment: @mu無 I'm sorry, but it wasn't solved. I ended up rewriting the whole code from scratch and the error disappeared. The answers here gave me good tips on how to improve my code, but not to solve the issue. Do you want me to mark one as "answer" anyway?

Comment: @renatov The general guideline is this -> http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/232644 In your case, since you ended up re-writing the code, that probably wouldn't be an answer, so I think you could accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you personally.

Comment: @mu無 ok, I'll accept the answer that most helped me in a general sense and put a note that it didn't actually solved the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your current code,

1. You don't count the root node currently
2. You return a 1 when there are no child, you should be returning 0 in that case. We similarly need to count the number of childs at each level, so `nodes_so_far` should be initialised with the length of the childs' list

Correcting for these, the function becomes:

```
def tree_nodes(tree):
    """Given a tree, returns the total amount of nodes it has."""
    def recursive_node_count(node):
        """Recursive count function."""
        childs = tree[node]
        if childs == None:
            return 0 # There are no child so return 0 in base case
        else:
            nodes_so_far = len(childs) # set to number of nodes passed
            for i in xrange(len(childs)):
                nodes_in_this_branch = recursive_node_count(childs[i])
                nodes_so_far += nodes_in_this_branch          
            return nodes_so_far
    root = tree['root']
    total_nodes = 1 + recursive_node_count(root) # Add 1 to count the root node
    return total_nodes
```

And in the dry run, this gives the output:

```
>>> tree = {0: [1], 1: [2], 2: [3, 4], 3: None, 4: None, 'root': 0}
>>> tree_nodes(tree)
5
```

Comment: The question was about the error that was being printed, this does not answer the question as asked.

Comment: @TylerCloutier Well thanks for the downvote, but I believe this can very well solve the OP's problem and so is a valid answer here.

Comment: It's not even clear what the problem is here, but you state 2 implying that they are the cause of the exception. In reality those would only affect the returned number of nodes, but won't cause the problem. Additionally, it is really only one problem, not two. The code was fine returning 1 node if there are no children. What really should be changed is beginning `nodes_so_far` at 1. Thus the root is counted implicitly.

Comment: Thank you, this is a perfectly valid answer. I upvoted your answer. I'll do the changes you suggested and tell if it solved the problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, the error still persists as it was despite the changes you suggested. But thanks for suggesting improvements to my code.

Comment: @renatov The error you are posting is unrelated to the code you've posted; the code will clearly work as I've demonstrated in my answer above. So I think you should debug a bit more, using `pdb.set_trace()` statements for finding the exact cause of the error, and ask a more refined question.

Comment: Ok, but I debugged it extensively and python's output error points to the recursion. Could you suggest me exactly what should I debug in my code?

Comment: If you wanted to count the 'root', then your code is incorrect as there should be 6 nodes in the tree, but your program only outputs 5. `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, root'. In this case `0` is the root, and thus my program will output the correct answer if the tree is input as `tree={0: None, 'root': 0}`

Comment: @mu無 Additionally, changing the initialization from `0` to `1` is truly the smallest edit you could make in order to make the code correct.

Comment: @TylerCloutier You win. Can we end the war now? :P

Comment: @renatov Refer https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pdb.html. Use a `pdb.set_trace()` call to check every part of your code. You can use multiple of these (these are like breakpoint statements), and check after each for loop whether the output for the previous steps is correct. I know the error points to the recursiveness, but its a big piece of code and python's error traces can be occasionaly (rarely) misleading.

Comment: This answer didn't actually solved the problem, but it was the one that most helped me improve my code. Thanks for your help, guys!

Answer (score 2):

Your answer was missing a couple of things. Here's the fixed version written around your code:

```
def tree_nodes(tree):
    def recursive_node_count(node):
        if node is None:
            return 0
        total_nodes = 1
        if tree[node]:
            for child in tree[node]:
                if child:
                    total_nodes += recursive_node_count(child)
        return total_nodes

    root = tree['root']
    total_nodes = recursive_node_count(root)
    return total_nodes

>>> tree = {0: [1], 1: [2], 2: [3, 4], 3: None, 4: None, 'root': 0}
>>> print tree_nodes(tree)
5
```

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to reproduce the error given the code that you provided. There is nothing wrong with it syntactically and indeed it runs fine. I will edit my answer if you can provide more insight into the error you are getting.

That being said, as noted by mu, this code will return the incorrect number of nodes. Specifically, it will return the number of leaves of the tree, since you only count the current node if it does not have any children. This problem can be fixed by initializing `nodes_so_far` to `1` representing the current node.

As a suggestion, you might want to switch the `for in xrange` python statement to a plain `for in` statement. The `for in` statement iterates over the list so that you don't have to index back into the list with in index number.

The code below illustrates these changes. This code will always output the correct number of nodes, even in the case when there is only one node and that is the root.

```
def tree_nodes(tree):
    """Given a tree, returns the total amount of nodes it has."""
    def recursive_node_count(node):
        """Recursive count function."""
        childs = tree[node]
        if not childs:
            # Return 1 for the current node.
            return 1
        else:
            # Initialize to 1 to count the current node.
            nodes_so_far = 1
            # Python for in statement
            for child in childs:
                nodes_for_child = recursive_node_count(child)
                nodes_so_far += nodes_for_child
            return nodes_so_far
    root = tree['root']
    total_nodes = recursive_node_count(root)
    return total_nodes

print(tree_nodes(tree={0: [1], 1: [2], 2: [3, 4], 3: None, 4: None, 'root': 0}))
print(tree_nodes(tree={0: None, 'root': 0}))
```